# Nginx Location Block for Dynamic Uri

Tags: nginx

example :
i have a list of uri in server (this file can be updated) :

```
/information/45212335
/information/45212355
/information/55212335
/information/85212335
```

is it possible to do like that with nginx? :

```
location ~ /information/(.+) {
 if($1 in file){
  deny all;
 }
}
```